# Intent.ACTION_SEND with image from resource

Tags: android, image, android-intent

I need to perform a realy simple thing - share an image with text.

What I found to be the best is the following

```
final Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, context
        .getString(R.string.fragment_etc_share_text));
sendIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
final Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"
        + getActivity().getPackageName() + "/"
        + R.drawable.share_attachment);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

`share_attachment` is an .jpg picture.

It works fine except for the image extension. I got something like "23244232" in the attachment. If I download the file and add an ".jpg" to its name - it opens well. But without the extension many social networks don't send it.

I tried to use assets but had no success as it's not a file actually on the runtime.

Using an external storage is not an option because the app must work even on old devices without SD card and be stable on USB plug in and out.